# In DNSSEC deplyment, when does the ZSK gets signed by KSK?

Tags: networking, security, dns

I have looked at many tutorials online on how to deploy DNSSEC. In a nutshell, the steps are: generate keys (ZSK and KSK), sign zone. The command I used to sign my `forward.com` zone file (for `com` zone) is:

```
dnssec-signzone -o com -S forward.com
```

The result I got is:

```
Verifying the zone using the following algorithms: RSASHA256.
Zone fully signed:
Algorithm: RSASHA256: KSKs: 1 active, 0 stand-by, 0 revoked
                      ZSKs: 1 active, 0 stand-by, 0 revoked
```

The point of the KSK is to sign the ZSK. When this happens? does it get signed automatically when I perform he zone signing?

Please, clarify to me. I need my ZSK to be signed by KSK. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZSKs and KSKs are published as regular 'DNSKEY' records in the same zone, and so they're signed like any other record, when the whole zone gets signed. The only special logic is:

- If it's a DNSKEY, CDNSKEY, or CDS record (or if the zone is KSK-only), then that record gets signed using KSKs *and* ZSKs. (That means that keys get signed by themselves, and ZSKs get signed by KSKs, and so on.)
- If it's a different record type, it gets signed using ZSKs.

This is automatic as part of the `dnssec-signzone` program (function `signset()` in BIND9's source code, `bin/dnssec/dnssec-signzone.c`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. So to clarify, the ZSK gets signed by the KSK automatically? Sorry for the confusion. But you say `and ZSKs get signed by KSKs` but before that you say `If it's a DNSKEY, CDNSKEY, or CDS record (or if the zone is KSK-only),` without mentioning the ZSK.

Comment: It applies to ZSKs because they are automatically added as DNSKEY records in your zone.

Comment: Thanks. I added both keys to the zone file simply using `cat` is this correct?

Comment: Well it won't hurt in any case, but I believe they get added automatically as part of the signing process. (Can't check at the moment.) ... However, instead of manual signing via command line (which you need to repeat every week or so), maybe BIND's "inline signing" would be more useful? If you activate `auto-dnssec maintain` and set the key path, it'll automatically do the rest.

Comment: What is the keys are in the same directory of the zone file? I want to do auto signing but can you give more details.

Comment: `key-directory` defaults to the same location as `directory`, which is probably already set to /etc/bind. See https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind/9.8.0-P4/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#options